# ElementUI datetime picker update on popper close

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuejs2, element-ui

I'm using ElementUI with Vue.js.

What I want to do is to use `el-date-picker` and listen for the update of the input only when the picker's popper closes (so earlier updates when selecting date via mouse click / direct text edit or via keyboard arrow controls won't trigger my 'special' update) - is it easily achievable? I was thinking of using custom popper class but not sure how to listen for close event to detect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with the `blur` event : https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/date-picker#events

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Andugal/pen/LoRwjR) if you want to play with it. And here is the code if you just want to run it :

```js
var Main = {
    methods: {
      blur () {
        console.log('hey')
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        value1: ''
      };
    }
  };
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.8.2/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.8.2/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<template>
  <div class="block">
    <span class="demonstration">Default</span>
    <el-date-picker
      v-model="value1"
      type="date"
      @blur="blur"
      placeholder="Pick a day">
    </el-date-picker>
  </div>
</template>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, it turned out that I was trying to listen for that event from wrapper component I've made for picker, but ended up with using plain elementUI one - that was the problem it wasn't working for me earlier.